# Merge Duplicate Account

Tags: merge

I need to merge duplicate Account, for that I loop through DuplicateRecordItem and put DuplicateRecordSetId and Set
into a map. Now I looped through duplicateRecordset and try to merge account but getting this error, (COMPILE ERROR: Invalid type for duplicate records).

```
Map<Id, Set<Id>> mapDuplicateRecordItem =  new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();

for(DuplicateRecordItem drI : [SELECT Id,RecordId, DuplicateRecordSetId FROM DuplicateRecordItem where DuplicateRecordSetId In : mapDuplicateRecordSet.keyset()]){

    if(!mapDuplicateRecordItem.containskey(drI.DuplicateRecordSetId)){
        mapDuplicateRecordItem.put(drI.DuplicateRecordSetId, new Set<Id>{drI.RecordId}); 
    }
    else{
        mapDuplicateRecordItem.get(drI.DuplicateRecordSetId).add(drI.RecordId); 
    }
} 

for(DuplicateRecordSet dr : [SELECT Id FROM DuplicateRecordSet where Id IN : mapDuplicateRecordItem.keyset()]){

    Set<Id>  setaccId =  mapDuplicateRecordItem.get(dr.Id);

    for(Account acc : [SELECT Id, name,BillingCountry, BillingState, ownerId FROM Account where ID In : setaccId]){ 

        //setacc.remove(acc.Id);
        Account accnt = new Account(ID = acc.id)
        if(!setaccId.contains(acc.Id)){ 
            merge acc setaccId; 
        }  
    }  
}
```

How to merge Account in this way ? or suggest any other idea Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to convert your `Set<Id>` to a `List<Id>`. You also need to make sure that the list contains no more than two duplicates at a time. See [Merging Records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_merge.htm) for acceptable forms. Basically, you can provide an `SObject`, `List<SObject>`, `Id`, or `List<Id>` as the second parameter to merge.